# Image button starts blink

Tags: html, image

I have this html code:

```
    <script>
        var image =  document.getElementById("LOC");

        function changeColor()
        {
            if (image.getAttribute('src') == "LOC.gif")
            {
                image.src = "LOC2.gif";
            }
            else
            {
                image.src = "LOC.gif";
            }
        }
    </script>
</body>

<img id ="LOC" src ="LOC.gif" onclick = "changeColor()"/>
```

I would like to do that if I click to image LOC.gif it starts blinking then if I press again, it change to LOC2.gif. Then again click -> starts blinking -> click again -> change back to LOC.gif

Thank you for your help!

Comment: You first need to not access the image BEFORE it is rendered. Then the image needs to be within the body tags. Just move `var image =  document.getElementById("LOC");` inside the function. To make it blink make LOC2.gif an animated gif

Comment: Voting to close as _This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers._

Comment: First thank you. It is GIF but it is not flashing so this GIF looks like a similar picture. for example .PNG.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a try of this

```js
var tId, images = [],
  isBlinking = false;
currImg = 0,

images[0] = new Image(); images[0].src = "https://placehold.it/100x100?text=LOC";
images[1] = new Image(); images[1].src = "https://placehold.it/100x100?text=LOC2";
images[2] = new Image(); images[2].src = "https://placehold.it/100x100?text=BLANK";

window.onload = function() {
  var img = document.getElementById("LOC");

  img.onclick = function() {
    if (isBlinking) {
      clearInterval(tId);
      isBlinking = false;
      currImg = currImg == 0 ? 1 : 0;
      img.src = images[currImg].src;

    } else {
      isBlinking = true;
      tId = setInterval(function() {
        var src = document.getElementById("LOC").src;
        // blink
        document.getElementById("LOC").src = src == images[currImg].src ? images[2].src : images[currImg].src;
      }, 300);
    }

  }
}
```

```html
Click image it starts blinking then click again, it changes image. Then again click -> starts blinking -> click again -> change back to original
<hr/>

<img id="LOC" src="https://placehold.it/100x100?text=LOC" />
```

Comment: :) Yes almost but after LOC2 -> LOC again. So LOC -> blank -> LOC2 -> blank -> and then again LOC

But I think I can do it from this one

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! :) After every blank there is a LOC then LOC2. What I would like is LOC BLANK LOC2 BLANK LOC BLANK LOC2...and so one :D:D

Comment: Thank you very very much for your help Sir! :)